# wxPython GUI Plot changed by Button Refresh using Variables from "Duration" and "Amplitude"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, wxpython

```
    self.figure0 = Figure()
    self.axes = self.figure0.add_subplot(111, axisbg="white")
    self.x_plot = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure0)
    self.draw_x()

def draw_x(self):
    value1 = self.SpinCtrl0.GetValue()
    value2 = self.SpinCtrl1.GetValue()
    x = np.arange(0.0,10,0.1)
    y = value1 * np.sin( x * value2 )

    self.axes.clear()
    self.axes.plot(x, y)
```

My Problem is now to make the plot stay in place but refresh its drawing.

Can anybody help ?!

P.S.: The Button is already set up and I fixed the position of the "x_plot" later in an other class.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand you, you would bind (wx.EVT_BUTTON) handler to your button and in that handler you call self.draw_x(), assuming above code is in the same class as your button handler.

Comment: Yes, the handler(wx.EVT_BUTTON) is bind to the button and it calls the def self.draw_x() function. It will appear an new plot but in the left upper corner of my frame. But it should actually update/refresh my already existing plot. 
I got stuck at that part. Sorry I started to learn python 4 weeks ago.
Handle me as a dummy :D